Rewarding the finding of zeroes of a hash function
I've been thinking about the following problem and haven't yet found a solution.
We have an arbitrary and public hash function $\text{Hash}$.
Could I possibly publish a function $F$ (that is, publish an algorithm that returns $F(M)$ given $M$) such that

$F(M)=K$ whenever $\text{Hash}(M)=0$, where $K$ is a previously defined private key that only I know;
There's no better way, for a stranger, to obtain $K$ than to find a zero of $\text{Hash}$ and pass it to $F$

A positive answer to this question would imply imply that it is possible to publish ``bounties'' for people achieving some computational work: for instance $K$ could be the private key of a cryptocurrency wallet. It could also allow for a timelock encryption mechanism based on proof-of-work.
Thanks in advance!

Not putting it as an answer, because it's not really a cryptography answer, but a number of cryptocurrencies already support this directly, and already have "bounty" wallets that you can unlock with the solution to a problem.

This sounds similar to the Hashcash algorithm.

@James_pic could you expand on that? What cryptos in particular?

Ethereum has Turing complete smart contracts, as do a few others, so it's possible to make payment conditional on anything that can be evaluated by a Turing machine. Even bitcoin support "bitcoin script", which whilst not Turing complete is sufficient to support "puzzle" wallets, that require you to know the preimage of a given hash. Of course this isn't what you asked for - there's no secret key K to be unlocked, you unlock the wallet with the solution to the problem directly.

What you describe is witness encryption.
In normal encryption, you encrypt a payload so that anyone with the corresponding decryption key can read it. In witness encryption, you encrypt so that anyone with the solution to a puzzle can read it. The person encrypting doesn't need to know the/a solution, and doesn't even need to know whether a solution exists.
I quote from the paper that introduced witness encryption, which motivates the problem similarly to you:

When we encrypt a message using a public-key encryption scheme, we allow the receiver to learn
our message only if he knows a secret key corresponding to his public key. What if we don’t really
care if he knows a secret key, but we do care if he knows a solution to a crossword puzzle that we
saw in the Times? Or if he knows a short proof for the Goldbach conjecture? Or, in general, the
solution to some NP search problem?
...
There are multiple real life examples where
a monetary award has been offered for the solution to a puzzle or problem including: the Clay
Institute Millennium Prize Problems [Ins] and the Eternity Puzzle [Web]. For these challenges
one could consider encoding the problem in terms of an NP-complete problem and encrypting the
password to a bank account containing the funds.

More formally, you encrypt with respect to a polynomial-time predicate $P$, and anyone who can produce a witness $w$ such that $P(w)=1$ can decrypt. In this case $P$ is the predicate that checks whether $\text{Hash}(w)\overset?= 0$.
Witness encryption is a theoretical feasibility, and can be constructed using very heavy machinery. I don't think you would be able to realistically implement your stated goal in practice, though.
